# Qt Creator - debug application with input from file

Tags: debugging, qt-creator

I usually test my app with

```
./myapp < test/test01.in
```

So in my run configuration I set the command line arguments to:

```
< test/test01.in
```

Now, when I launched the debug session, I came across the following error:

```
Debugging complex shell commands in a terminal is currently not supported.
```

Can I debug my app in QtCreator without having to type all the input by hand/copying it directly into the terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need correctly fill Projects->Run fields (*"Executable", "Command line arguments", "Working directory"*) and left *"Run in terminal"* checkbox in unchecked state.

After that you can start debugging(F5).